# How to add more columns to a grouped result in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have this LINQ statement which produces a collection of strings:

[image]

How do I change this LINQ query so that it produces a collection of int/string arrays so that I can include the language id as well in my result?

Something like this:

```
from u in Users
join l in Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
group u by l.Name into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Id = l.Id, NameAndCount = g.Key + " (" + g.Count() + ")" }
```

### Unsuccessful Tries:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a little change in your code.
Instead of group by Users, you should group it by Languages and two fields/columns for the group.

```
from u in Users
join l in Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
group l by new { l.Id, l.Name } into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Id = g.Key.Id, NameAndCount = g.Key.Name + " (" + g.Count() + ")" }
```

---

Another case:

Note that every fields we use for grouping can be accessed from `.Key` and you can name the fields

example 1.

```
// ...
group l by new { MyId = l.Id, MyName = l.Name } into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Id = g.Key.MyId, NameAndCount = g.Key.MyName + " (" + g.Count() + ")" }
```

And if in another case, we don't want to lose the collection in the result, just add a UserList variable like the example below.

example 2:

```
// ...
group l by new { l.Id, l.Name } into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Id = g.Key.Id, NameAndCount = g.Key.Name + " (" + g.Count() + ")", UserList = g.ToList() }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply group your records by `Id` and then fetch `Name` using `FirstOrDefault`

```
from u in Users
join l in Languages on u.LanguageId equals l.Id
group l by l.Id into g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Id = g.Key, NameAndCount = g.First().Name + " (" + g.Count() + ")" }
```

Comment: Although this tells me: `CS1061 'User' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be found`

Comment: Yeah, I got it, you need to group Language instead of users, I have updated my answer, please check!!

Comment: That makes sense, but now it tells me: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'. Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.`

Comment: Didn't realize that, updated one more time!! Now will work for you

Comment: I understand the intent of this syntax, but it now tells me: `SQL logic error or missing databasenear "(": syntax error` even if I simply put `select new { Id = g.Key, NameAndCount = g.First().Name }`.

Comment: @EdwardTanguay I ran the code and didn't find any error after the last update, please have a look https://dotnetfiddle.net/g02hZl

Comment: Ipsit, very nice. I copied your .NET Fiddle code into my LINQPad and it works there as well. Interesting that I get that error when the data comes from my SQLite database (see screenshot above). In any case, Maulana's approach above: `group l by new { l.Id, l.Name } into g` and it works with my SQLite implementation.